# Variadic template not compiled

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>    
void out()                   // line 4
{
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void out(T value, Args... args)        // line 9
{
    std::cout << value;
    out(args...);    // line 12
}

int main()
{
    out("12345", std::endl);    // line 17
    return 0;
}
```

Build errors:

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -pthread -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
../main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
../main.cpp:17:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘out(const char [6], <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
../main.cpp:17:24: note: candidates are:
../main.cpp:4:6: note: template<class T> void out()
../main.cpp:4:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
../main.cpp:17:24: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
../main.cpp:9:6: note: void out(T, Args ...) [with T = const char*; Args = {}]
../main.cpp:9:6: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

I want this program to give the same result as `std::cout << "12345" << std::endl;` What is wrong in the template function?

Comment: You're missing a `.` in the unpacking statement. Change it to `args...`.

Comment: Editing the question, there are another messages with ...

Comment: @AlexFarber My apologies...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you made your no argument version of `out` be a template, and it cannot be called without explicitly supplying template arguments. Thus

```
void out() {}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void out(T value, Args... args) {
    std::cout << value;
    out(args...);
}

int main() {
    out(1, 2.0, "3");
    return 0;
}
```

works as intended.

Comment: The words you were looking for are "argument type-deduction".

Answer (score 3):

There is a syntax error (a missning `.`) that makes the compiler go crazy.

After that, you may also have a problem with the `out("12345", std::endl)` call, being `std::endl` an overridden function that compiler cannot choose from (just cast it as `static_cast<std::ostream&(*)(std::ostream&)>(std::endl)`)

Also, the recursion in `out` ends in a `out()` call, but there is no out with 0 parameters.(see also yuri answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20879525/924727 )

Comment: Thanks. `..` was typo, fixed. Removing `std::endl` from the call doesn't help, the problem is in template itself, I guess.

Comment: After removing the first `template` line it looks better. You are right, `std::endl` is not compiled. But your casting is not working: `invalid static_cast from type ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to type ‘std::ostream&(std::ostream&) {aka std::basic_ostream<char>&(std::basic_ostream<char>&)}`

Comment: OOPS: see the edit (forgot a `(*)` )

Comment: Thanks. I posted another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20879611/stdendl-and-variadic-template Write the answer there.